# Accessing the iPhone's USB port?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way for developer to send data to the iPhone's USB port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no way to do this with the SDK. If this is something you'd like to see, you should [file an enhancement request](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

Not currently.  USB functionality is expanded in [iPhone OS 3.0](http://www.apple.com/iphone/preview-iphone-os/).